# What are the tiers of loot?

Tags: anthem

Anthem is a gear driven game, and I've seen videos mentioning Legendary and Masterwork items.

What are the actual tiers of gear in the game? Are Masterworks the highest tier?

Comment: Be careful with this kind of question as Anthem is not yet released. Currently this question would be off-topic as per the help center

Comment: The game has been released to Origin Access subscribers since the 15th.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 6 different tiers of gear in Anthem, the order from lowest to highest is as follows:

1. Common (White)
2. Uncommon (Green)
3. Rare (Blue)
4. Epic (Purple)
5. Masterwork (Orange)
6. Legendary (Yellowish)

In addition to the colors, tiers can be identified by the number of triangles displayed, ranging from none for Common rarity all the way up to five for Legendary gear.

Comment: They also seem to display a certain number of triangles to denote the tier. With Legendary gear showing 5 triangles.https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/518001069415202816/547430113290223631/unknown.png

Comment: @DavidYell good point, edited my answer accordingly.